# Populate checkboxes based on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In a form, I do have a list of industries populated from db. I want to populate a list of checkboxes based on the selected industry.

I tried the below but its not working. **Can you please help**. I am still learning to code and would really appreciate your help.

**index.php**

```
// The dropdown is populated from DB
<select class="set_industry">
    <option value="1">Healthcare</option>
    <option value="2">Food & Beverage</option>
    <option value="3">Real Estate</option>
</select>
// Preferably the selection would produce var $ind_id
.
.
.
.
// I want the below to be executed based on the selection from above

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
  $ind_id = $_POST['id'];
  $x="SELECT * FROM srv_tbl WHERE ind_id=$ind_id";
  $res=query($x);

  while ($y=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) { ?>
  <div>
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $y['srv_id'] ?>"> <?php echo $y['srv_name'] ?>
    </label>
  </div>
<?php } 
} ?>

<script>Link to js script</script>
```

**script.js**

```
$(".set_industry").on('change', function(){ 
    var ind_id = $(this).attr("value");
    $.post("index.php", {id: ind_id}, function());  
});
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error. I can only see the dropdown with the options. I even tried to echo the $ind_id without success. I think the var is not being passed back throug the $_POST

Comment: I recommend reading https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/ for a better way to set up the ajax call.itll be worth your time to set that up right (I just finished retrofitting an old plugin with this and it was a pain)

Comment: You may wanna check if you are getting anything from your database!

Comment: I do get results from db if I replace $ind_id with constant.

Comment: PHP will execute before any code is sent to the Client (Browser). Everything that happens after that, you will want to use AJAX, which it looks like you're trying with your `$.post()`, but you're not understanding that you should have the PHP that handles the JavaScript on a separate PHP page. So, it's okay to build the initial page using PHP that generates HTML, but after that you should use AJAX using a totally separate PHP page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate your PHP code .

**index.php**

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['id'])) {

  $ind_id = $_POST['id'];
  $x="SELECT * FROM srv_tbl WHERE ind_id=$ind_id";
  $res=query($x);

  $returnString = '';   
  while ($y=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

     $returnString .= '<div><label><input type="checkbox" value=".$y['srv_id'].">.$y['srv_name'].</label></div>';
  }

  echo $returnString;
} ?>
```

add new div to your HTML page

**index.html**

```
<select class="set_industry">
    <option value="1">Healthcare</option>
    <option value="2">Food & Beverage</option>
    <option value="3">Real Estate</option>
</select>

<div id="response"></div>

<script>Link to js script</script>
```

Do these changes to your **script.js**

```
$(".set_industry").on('change', function(){ 
    var ind_id = $(this).attr("value");
    $.post("index.php", {id: ind_id}, function(data){

       $("#response").html( data );
    });  
});
```